# save instance state in AndroidViewModel

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I'm learning to use MVVM for my application, because of this I have to extend my viewmodel using AndroidViewModel instead of ViewModel, so that I can have the application contextfor
the repository stuff, but this is not the problem.

The problem is that I used to have `savedStateHandle` as parameter in the constructor the viewmodel that extends `ViewModel` as below:

```java
public class MainViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private static String SAVED_KEY_STARTED = "started";
    private MutableLiveData<Boolean> isStarted;
    SavedStateHandle savedState;

    public MainViewModel(SavedStateHandle savedStateHandle){
        savedState = savedStateHandle;

        isStarted = new MutableLiveData(Boolean.False);

        if(savedStateHandle.contains(SAVED_KEY_STARTED)){
                isStarted.setValue(savedStateHandle.get(SAVED_KEY_STARTED));
        }
    }

    // some other getters setters that set values into `savedState` on the fly
    ...
}
```

Now, using viewmodel that extends AndroidViewModel, the contructor no longer has this, instead it only pass in a application context. How can I save and retrieve instance state using AndroidViewModel.

```java
public class MainViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    public MainViewModel(Application application){
    }
}
```

Added:
code to retrieve viewmodel

```java
// im using this for a fragment within my main activity 
viewModel =
        new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity(),
                ViewModelProvider
                        .AndroidViewModelFactory
                        .getInstance(requireActivity().getApplication())
        ).get(MainViewModel.class);
```

Comment: Have you tried having your constructor take both an Application and a SavedStateHandle? That works just fine, even if you only pass the Application to the super constructor.

Comment: adding in savesatehandle as constructor param doesn't work for me. Do I need to change the way I retrieve viewmodelprovider? I have added the code that I retrieve viewmodel in the question.

Comment: I've tried removing the factory then it works, I'm not entirely sure what is the purpose of having this factory tho... cuz i got this from some where else...

Comment: Yeah, the default factory is what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
viewModel =
        new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(MainViewModel.class);
```

```
public class MainViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    public MainViewModel(Application application, SavedStateHandle savedStateHandle){
        super(Application application);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).